# c# How to set the Oracle Home on the connection string?

Tags: c#, oracle, connection

I have two Oracle Homes in my machine ( Oracle 9 and Oracle 11) . Oracle 9 Home is the default home. How can I  set my connection string to use Oracle 11's Home?

Comment: Tell us what happens when you change ORACLE_HOME on the system level (in different words, when you change the system variable ORACLE_HOME)

Comment: its an ambiguous question. if I understood correct then If you are using ODBC for database then it shouldn't matter as both the databases listeners would be configured to different ports.

Comment: It depends how you connect to database, i.e. which provider to you use. For example for Oracle ADO.NET (Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle) you cannot have more than one provider installed on one machine.

Answer (score 0):

In windows you could use the LOCAL environment variable to point to the tns_alias that connects to your requested services.
On *nix platforms you can use the TWO_TASK variable to do the same.

In both cases you use whatever software the ORACLE_HOME points to and use sql*net to connect to your database. In your situation you use the client software from the Oracle 9 Home and you can connect to a database that is running Oracle 11 software. (not 100% sure about the ability to connect to v11 with a v9 client but if this is possible, this is the way to do that)

If you really want to use the v11 client software, you need to setup your environment where ORACLE_HOME points to the v11 software location and PATH points to your v11 ORACLE_HOME/bin. You could still use LOCAL or TWO_TASK to connect but if your database runs on the same host, you can also set ORACLE_SID (and unset TWO_TASK) to your default connection.